# Finding a pair of non-overlapping bit vectors

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I give you a list of $n$ bitvectors of width $k$. Your goal is to return two bitvectors from the list that have no 1s in common, or else to report that no such pair exists.

For example, if I give you $[00110, 01100, 11000]$ then the only solution is $\{00110, 11000\}$. Alternatively, the input $[111, 011, 110, 101]$ has no solution. And any list that contains the all-zero bitvector $000...0$ and another element $e$ has a trivial solution $\{e, 000...0\}$.

Here's a slightly harder example, with no solution (each row is a bit vector, the black squares are 1s and the white squares are 0s):

```
■ ■ ■ ■ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □
■ □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ □ □ □ □ □ □ 
■ □ □ □ □ □ □ ■ ■ ■ □ □ □
■ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ ■ ■ ■
□ ■ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □ ■ ■ □ □
□ ■ □ □ ■ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □ ■
□ ■ □ □ □ □ ■ ■ □ □ □ ■ □ <-- All row pairs share a black square
□ □ ■ □ □ □ ■ □ ■ □ ■ □ □
□ □ ■ □ □ ■ □ ■ □ □ □ □ ■
□ □ ■ □ ■ □ □ □ □ ■ □ ■ □
□ □ □ ■ ■ □ □ ■ □ □ ■ □ □
□ □ □ ■ □ □ ■ □ □ ■ □ □ ■
□ □ □ ■ □ ■ □ □ ■ □ □ ■ □
```

How efficiently can two non-overlapping bitvectors be found, or be shown not to exist?

The naive algorithm, where you just compare every possible pair, is $O(n^2 k)$. Is it possible to do better?

Comment: A possible reduction : You have a graph $G$ with one vertex for each vector and an edge between two vertices if the two corresponding vectors have a 1 in common. You want to know if the graph diameter is $\geq 2$. But it seems difficult to go faster than $O(n^2k)$.

Comment: @FrançoisGodi Any connected graph component with three nodes and a missing edge has diameter at least two. With an adjacency list representation, it takes $O(V)$ time to check that.

Comment: @Strilanc Sure,  if there is no solution the graph is complete (more clear than diameter=1, you are right), but computing the adjacency list representation could be long.

Comment: Is $k$ smaller than the word width of your machine?

Comment: @Raphael You cheat.. Anyway, if it's smaller it's a constant and we have immediately an $O(n^2)$ algorithm.

Comment: @Raphael Nope. Though I suppose you could use the [unit cost ram model to shave off a factor of log(n)](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2009/05/shaving-logs-with-unit-cost.html).

Comment: @Strilanc I see how you could shave off a factor of log(k) but log(n) ??

Comment: @FrançoisGodi Read the link. A common assumption is that machine words have size O(log n), and that would allow you to compare the bit vectors in log(n) sized chunks.

Comment: Reformulation: you want all pairs $(x,y)$ with $x \mathbin{\text{NAND}} y = 2^k-1$ or, equivalently, $x \mathbin{\text{AND}} y = 0$ (with bitwise logical operation).

Comment: @Raphael No, he just wants to know if such a pair exists.

Comment: 1. Do you care more about provable worst-case running time, or about efficiency in practice?  2. Have you looked at divide-and-conquer approaches?  e.g., look at only the first $k/2$ bits of each word, and recursively enumerate all pairs that have no 1 in common in their first $k/2$ bits, then check the last $k/2$ bits for those pairs.  Yes, this could go bad for some inputs, but I wonder if it might help if you make some heuristic assumptions on the distribution of the bitvectors (or if you randomly permute all the bitvectors using the same permutation $\pi$ first).

Comment: @D.W. This is not for a practical problem I need to solve; it's just a curiosity. I happen to care about the worst case or expected case running times against an adversary creating the inputs.

Comment: Perhaps you can take inspiration from some string matching algorithms, perhaps Aho–Corasick. I suppose you could define your own "equality" relation where $0=0=1$ but $1\not=1$.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden That sounds like it would violate invariants that the data structure probably relies on. In particular, that equality should be transitive. I've been thinking about using a trie already and I don't see how to avoid a factor-of-2 blowup every time the query bitmask has a 0.

Comment: A particularly hard regime is where the density is low (most bitvectors are mostly 0).  For instance, suppose that for every bit position $i$, the fraction of bitvectors that are 1 in position $i$ is $<1/\sqrt{k}$.  Then it's guaranteed that there exists a pair of non-overlapping bitvectors -- but it's not clear how to find it efficiently.  Would it be enough to report "a pair exists" without being able to find it, or do you definitely want to find such a pair?  If you do, it might be worth thinking to see if we can find an algorithm for that special case of the problem.

Comment: this is all great/ significant effort but would like to see it tied into the literature & nearest problems considered in the literature. suspect it is likely related some standard questions in eg study of set systems as studied eg by erdos. also suspect it is naturally defined as a hypergraph problem. (have to think it all out/ research it more)... like that it has spurred interest but wish there was at least some cursory ref to the motivation/ bkg, ideally more than that... it looks like it is what is known as "pairwise set intersection" problem...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Warmup: random bitvectors

As a warm-up, we can start with the case where each bitvector is chosen iid uniformly at random.  Then it turns out that the problem can be solved in $O(n^{1.6} \min(k, \lg n))$ time (more precisely, the $1.6$ can be replaced with $\lg 3$).

We'll consider the following two-set variant of the problem:

Given sets $S,T \subseteq \{0,1\}^k$ of bitvectors, determine where there exists a non-overlapping pair $s \in S, t \in T$.

The basic technique to solve this is divide-and-conquer.  Here is a $O(n^{1.6} k)$ time algorithm using divide-and-conquer:

1. Split $S$ and $T$ based upon the first bit position.  In other words, form $S_0 = \{s \in S : s_0=0\}$, $S_1 = \{s \in S : s_0 = 1\}$, $T_0 = \{t \in T : t_0 = 0\}$, $T_1 = \{t \in T : t_0 = 1\}$.
2. Now recursively look for a non-overlapping pair from $S_0,T_0$, from $S_0,T_1$, and from $T_1,S_0$.  If any recursive call finds a non-overlapping pair, output it, otherwise output "No overlapping pair exists".

Since all bitvectors are chosen at random, we can expect $|S_b| \approx |S|/2$ and $|T_b| \approx |T|/2$.  Thus, we have three recursive calls, and we've reduced the size of the problem by a factor of two (both sets are reduced in size by a factor of two).  After $\lg \min(|S|,|T|)$ splits, one of the two sets is down to size 1, and the problem can be solved in linear time.  We get a recurrence relation along the lines of $T(n) = 3T(n/2) + O(nk)$, whose solution is $T(n) = O(n^{1.6} k)$.  Accounting for running time more precisely in the two-set case, we see the running time is $O(\min(|S|,|T|)^{0.6} \max(|S|,|T|) k)$.

This can be further improved, by noting that if $k \ge 2.5\lg n+100$, then the probability that a non-overlapping pair exists is exponentially small.  In particular, if $x,y$ are two random vectors, the probability that they're non-overlapping is $(3/4)^k$.  If $|S|=|T|=n$, there are $n^2$ such pairs, so by a union bound, the probability a non-overlapping pair exists is at most $n^2 (3/4)^k$.  When $k \ge 2.5 \lg n+100$, this is $\le 1/2^{100}$.  So, as a pre-processing step, if $k \ge 2.5 \lg n + 100$, then we can immediately return "No non-overlapping pair exists" (the probability this is incorrect is negligibly small), otherwise we run the above algorithm.

Thus we achieve a running time of $O(n^{1.6} \min(k, \lg n))$ (or $O(\min(|S|,|T|)^{0.6} \max(|S|,|T|) \min(k, \lg n))$ for the two-set variant proposed above), for the special case where the bitvectors are chosen uniformly at random.

Of course, this is not a worst-case analysis.  Random bitvectors are considerably easier than the worst case -- but let's treat it as a warmup, to get some ideas that perhaps we can apply to the general case.

### Lessons from the warmup

We can learn a few lessons from the warmup above.  First, divide-and-conquer (splitting on a bit position) seems helpful.  Second, you want to split on a bit position with as many $1$'s in that position as possible; the more $0$'s there are, the less reduction in subproblem size you get.

Third, this suggests that the problem gets harder as the density of $1$'s gets smaller -- if there are very few $1$'s among the bitvectors (they are mostly $0$'s), the problem looks quite hard, as each split reduces the size of the subproblems a little bit.  So, define the density $\Delta$ to be the fraction of bits that are $1$ (i.e., out of all $nk$ bits), and the density of bit position $i$ to be the fraction of bitvectors that are $1$ at position $i$.

### Handling very low density

As a next step, we might wonder what happens if the density is extremely small.  It turns out that if the density in every bit position is smaller than $1/\sqrt{k}$, we're guaranteed that a non-overlapping pair exists: there is a (non-constructive) existence argument showing that some non-overlapping pair must exist.  This doesn't help us find it, but at least we know it exists.

Why is this the case?  Let's say that a pair of bitvectors $x,y$ is *covered* by bit position $i$ if $x_i=y_i=1$.  Note that every pair of overlapping bitvectors must be covered by some bit position.  Now, if we fix a particular bit position $i$, the number of pairs that can be covered by that bit position is at most $(n \Delta(i))^2 < n^2/k$.  Summing across all $k$ of the bit positions, we find that the total number of pairs that are covered by some bit position is $< n^2$.  This means there must exist some pair that's not covered by any bit position, which implies that this pair is non-overlapping.  So if the density is sufficiently low in every bit position, then a non-overlapping pair surely exists.

However, I'm at a loss to identify a fast algorithm to find such a non-overlapping pair, in these regime, even though one is guaranteed to exist.  I don't immediately see any techniques that would yield a running time that has a sub-quadratic dependence on $n$.  So, this is a nice special case to focus on, if you want to spend some time thinking about this problem.

### Towards a general-case algorithm

In the general case, a natural heuristic seems to be: pick the bit position $i$ with the most number of $1$'s (i.e., with the highest density), and split on it.  In other words:

1. Find a bit position $i$ that maximizes $\Delta(i)$.
2. Split $S$ and $T$ based upon bit position $i$.  In other words, form $S_0 = \{s \in S : s_i=0\}$, $S_1 = \{s \in S : s_i = 1\}$, $T_0 = \{t \in T : t_i = 0\}$, $T_1 = \{t \in T : t_i = 1\}$.
3. Now recursively look for a non-overlapping pair from $S_0,T_0$, from $S_0,T_1$, and from $T_1,S_0$.  If any recursive call finds a non-overlapping pair, output it, otherwise output "No overlapping pair exists".

The challenge is to analyze its performance in the worst case.

Let's assume that as a pre-processing step we first compute the density of every bit position.  Also, if $\Delta(i) < 1/\sqrt{k}$ for every $i$, assume that the pre-processing step outputs "An overlapping pair exists" (I realize that this doesn't exhibit an example of an overlapping pair, but let's set that aside as a separate challenge).  All this can be done in $O(nk)$ time.  The density information can be maintained efficiently as we do recursive calls; it won't be the dominant contributor to running time.

What will the running time of this procedure be?  I'm not sure, but here are a few observations that might help.  Each level of recursion reduces the problem size by about $n/\sqrt{k}$ bitvectors (e.g., from $n$ bitvectors to $n-n/\sqrt{k}$ bitvectors).  Therefore, the recursion can only go about $\sqrt{k}$ levels deep.  However, I'm not immediately sure how to count the number of leaves in the recursion tree (there are a lot less than $3^{\sqrt{k}}$ leaves), so I'm not sure what running time this should lead to.

Comment: ad low density: this seems to be some kind of pigeon-hole argument. Maybe if we use your general idea (split w.r.t. the column with the most ones), we get better bounds because the $(S_1, T_1)$-case (we don't recurse to) already gets rid of "most" ones?

Comment: The total number of ones may be a useful parameter. You have already shown a lower bound we can use for cutting off the tree; can we show upper bounds, too? For example, if there are more than $ck$ ones, we have at least $c$ overlaps.

Comment: By the way, how do you propose we do the first split; arbitrarily? Why not just split the whole input set w.r.t. some column $i$? We only need to recurse in the $0$-case (there is no solution among those that share a one at $i$). In expectation, that gives via $T(n) = T(n/2) + O(nk)$ a bound of $O(nk)$ (if $k$ fixed). For a general bound, you have shown that we can (assuming the lower-bound-cutoff you propose) that we get rid of at least $n/\sqrt{k}$ elements with every split, which seems to imply an $O(nk)$ worst-case bound. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, that's wrong, of course, since it does not consider 0-1-mismatches. That's what I get for trying to think before breakfast, I guess.

Comment: @Raphael, there are two issues: (a) the vectors might be mostly zeros, so you can't count on getting a 50-50 split; the recurrence would be something more like $T(n) = T((n-n/\sqrt{k})k)+O(nk)$, (b) more importantly, it's not enough to just recurse on the 0-subset; you also need to examine pairings between a vector from the 0-subset and a vector from the 1-subset, so there's an additional recursion or two to do.  (I think?  I hope I got that right.)

Comment: (a) Yes, not $1/2$, but $\Delta(i) \geq 1/\sqrt{k}$, or don't we? Then, $a$ in the Master Theorem would be $(1 - 1/\sqrt{k})$, which is still fair. I don't know where you get the factor $k$ from? (b) Yes, that was what I meant by my latest comment. :/

Comment: @Raphael, (a) Yes, you're right.  Sorry, the extra $k$ was a mistake.  (b) Got it.  OK, we're on the same page then.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

## Faster solution when $n \approx k$, using matrix multiplication

Suppose that $n = k$. Our goal is to do better than an $O(n^2k) = O(n^3)$ running time.

We can think of the bitvectors and bit positions as nodes in a graph. There is an edge between a bitvector node and a bit position node when the bitvector has a 1 in that position. The resulting graph is bipartite (with the bitvector-representing nodes on one side and the bitposition-representing nodes on the other), and has $n + k = 2n$ nodes.

Given the adjacency matrix $M$ of a graph, we can tell if there is a two-hop path between two vertices [by squaring](http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Matrices.pdf) $M$ and checking if the resulting matrix has an "edge" between those two vertices (i.e. the edge's entry in the squared matrix is non-zero). For our purposes, a zero entry in the squared adjacency matrix corresponds to a non-overlapping pair of bitvectors (i.e. a solution). A lack of any zeroes means there's no solution.

Squaring an n x n matrix can be done in $O(n^\omega)$ time, where [$\omega$ is known to be under $2.373$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) and conjectured to be $2$.

So the algorithm is:

- Convert the bitvectors and bit positions into a bipartite graph with $n+k$ nodes and at most $nk$ edges. This takes $O(nk)$ time.
- Compute the adjacency matrix of the graph. This takes $O((n+k)^2)$ time and space.
- Square the adjacency matrix. This takes $O((n+k)^\omega)$ time.
- Search the bitvector section of the adjacency matrix for zero entries. This takes $O(n^2)$ time.

The most expensive step is squaring the adjacency matrix. If $n=k$ then the overall algorithm takes $O((n+k)^\omega) = O(n^\omega)$  time, which is better than the naive $O(n^3)$ time.

This solution is also faster when $k$ grows not-too-much-slower and not-too-much-faster than $n$. As long as $k \in \Omega(n^{\omega-2})$ and $k \in O(n^\frac{2}{\omega-1})$, then $(n+k)^\omega$ is better than $n^2 k$. For $w \approx 2.373$ that translates to $n^{0.731} \leq k \leq n^{1.373}$ (asymptotically). If $w$ limits to 2, then the bounds widen towards $n^\epsilon \leq k \leq n^{2-\epsilon}$.

Comment: 1. This is also better than the naive solution if $k=\Omega(n)$ but $k=o(n^{1.457})$.  2. If $k \ge n$, a heuristic could be: pick a random subset of $n$ bit positions, restrict to those bit positions and use matrix multiplication to enumerate all pairs that don't overlap in those $n$ bit positions; for each such pair, check if it solves the original problem.  If there aren't many pairs that don't overlap in those $n$ bit positions, this provides a speedup over the naive algorithm.  However I don't know a good upper bound on the number of such pairs.

Answer (score 4):

This is equivalent to finding a bit vector which is a subset of the complement of another vector; ie its 1's occur only where 0's occur in the other.

If k (or the number of 1's) is small, you can get $O(n2^k)$ time by simply generating all the subsets of the complement of each bitvector and putting them in a trie (using backtracking).  If a bitvector is found in the trie (we can check each before complement-subset insertion) then we have a non-overlapping pair.

If the number of 1's or 0's is bounded to an even lower number than k, then the exponent can be replaced by that.  The subset-indexing can be on either each vector or its complement, so long as probing uses the opposite.

There's also a [scheme](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~savnik/papers/cdares13.pdf) for superset-finding in a trie that only stores each vector only once, but does bit-skipping during probes for what I believe is similar aggregate complexity; ie it has $o(k)$ insertion but $o(2^k)$ searches.

Comment: thanks. The complexity of your solution is $\sim n 2^{(1-p)k}$, where $p$ is the probability of 1's in the bitvector. A couple of implementation details: though this is a slight improvement, there's no need to compute and store the complements in the trie. Just following the complementary branches when checking for a non-overlapping match is enough. And, taking the 0's directly as wildcards, no special wildcard is needed, either.

Answer (score 2):

Represent the bit vectors as an $n\times k$ matrix $M$. Take $i$ and $j$ between 1 and $n$.

$$\begin{align}
(MM^T)_{ij} = \sum_l M_{il}M_{jl}
\end{align}.$$

$(MM^T)_{ij}$, the dot product of the $i$th and $j$th vector, is non-zero if, and only if, vectors $i$ and $j$ share a common 1. So, to find a solution, compute $MM^T$ and return the position of a zero entry, if such an entry exists.

**Complexity**

Using naive multiplication, this requires $O(n^2k)$ arithmetic operations. If $n=k$, it takes $O(n^{2.37})$ operations using the utterly impractical Coppersmith-Winograd algorithm, or $O(n^{2.8})$ using the Strassen algorithm. If $k=O(n^{0.302})$, then the problem [may be solved](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1111) using $n^{2 + o(1)}$ operations.

Comment: How is this different from [Strilanc's answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43873/755)?

Comment: @D.W. Using an $n$-by-$k$ matrix instead of an $(n+k)$-by-$(n+k)$ matrix is an improvement. Also it mentions a way to cut off the factor of k when k << n, so that might be useful.